# How to remove remaining files after removing an application

Tags: 11.10

I installed Zekr application and tried to change the fonts by deleting the default lines.  Even after removing the application and reinstalling it again the default configuration is not restored which is due to the remanent files.

Answer (score 1):

remove it with the purge option

```
sudo apt-get purge zekr
```

The difference is purge removes the configuration files, remove does not.

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Removal_commands

Answer (score 0):

'purge' is what you need.

Otherwise, look at:

[Package management with APT](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

other useful commands

removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

remove unmet dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

remove .deb archives from packages no longer installed

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

clear files from Aptitude cache ( /var/cache/apt/archives )

```
sudo apt-get clean
```